# PostgreSQL: Bad query performance caused by unused index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-9.2

we have a query to get all jobs with changes inside a certain time period. Depending on the selected period the performance goes from <100 milliseconds for a day to ~7 seconds for a week.

I found that if the time period is small enough, the index is used and the query is fast. If the period gets too big, the index is not used and the query becomes slow.

The server runs with version `9.2`.

Why is this caused and how to fix this issue?

Create script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Job" 
(
    "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "serial" TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_Job_serial" ON "Job" ("serial" ASC);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Property" 
(
    "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Timestamp"
(
    "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "usSince1970" BIGINT NOT NULL ,
    "localTime" TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX "index_Timestamp_usSince1970" ON "Timestamp" USING btree ("usSince1970");

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Changes" 
(
    "idJob" INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    "idProperty" INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    "idTimestamp" INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    "value1" decimal(25,5),
    "value2" INTEGER ,
    "value3" TEXT ,
    PRIMARY KEY ("idJob", "idProperty", "idTimestamp") ,
    FOREIGN KEY ("idJob" ) REFERENCES "Job" ("id" ) ,
    FOREIGN KEY ("idProperty" ) REFERENCES "Property" ("id" ) ,
    FOREIGN KEY ("idTimestamp" ) REFERENCES "Timestamp" ("id" )
);
CREATE INDEX "index_Changes_idJob" ON "Changes" ("idJob" ASC);
CREATE INDEX "index_Changes_idProperty" ON "Changes" ("idProperty" ASC);
CREATE INDEX "index_Changes_idTimestamp" ON "Changes" ("idTimestamp" DESC);
```

Fast query:

```
-- fast query (1 day)
SELECT DISTINCT "idJob"
FROM "Changes" 
INNER JOIN "Timestamp" ON "Timestamp"."id" = "Changes"."idTimestamp" 
WHERE "Timestamp"."usSince1970" between 1584831600000000 and 1584745200000000 

-- explain
HashAggregate  (cost=26383.48..26444.33 rows=6085 width=4) (actual time=8.039..8.078 rows=179 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..26368.26 rows=6085 width=4) (actual time=0.031..7.059 rows=6498 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using "index_Timestamp_usSince1970" on "Timestamp"  (cost=0.00..96.25 rows=2510 width=4) (actual time=0.022..0.514 rows=2671 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (("usSince1970" >= 1584745200000000::bigint) AND ("usSince1970" <= 1584831600000000::bigint))
        ->  Index Scan using "index_Changes_idTimestamp" on "Changes"  (cost=0.00..10.27 rows=20 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=2 loops=2671)
              Index Cond: ("idTimestamp" = "Timestamp".id)
Total runtime: 8.204 ms
```

Slow query:

```
-- slow query (7 days)
SELECT distinct "idJob"
FROM "Changes" 
INNER JOIN "Timestamp" ON "Timestamp"."id" = "Changes"."idTimestamp" 
WHERE "Timestamp"."usSince1970" between 1583708400000000 and 1584313200000000

-- explain
Unique  (cost=570694.82..571824.16 rows=92521 width=4) (actual time=8869.569..8930.545 rows=3695 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=570694.82..571259.49 rows=225867 width=4) (actual time=8869.568..8915.372 rows=260705 loops=1)
        Sort Key: "Changes"."idJob"
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3552kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=4926.44..547518.97 rows=225867 width=4) (actual time=6325.494..8734.353 rows=260705 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ("Changes"."idTimestamp" = "Timestamp".id)
              ->  Seq Scan on "Changes"  (cost=0.00..250722.43 rows=16238343 width=8) (actual time=0.004..2505.794 rows=16238343 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=3397.79..3397.79 rows=93172 width=4) (actual time=42.392..42.392 rows=107093 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 4096  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 948kB
                    ->  Index Scan using "index_Timestamp_usSince1970" on "Timestamp"  (cost=0.00..3397.79 rows=93172 width=4) (actual time=0.006..20.831 rows=107093 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (("usSince1970" >= 1583708400000000::bigint) AND ("usSince1970" <= 1584313200000000::bigint))
Total runtime: 8932.374 ms
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: agreed and noted :)

Comment: Also: there is no reason to store timestamps in bigints.

Comment: And, in the slow query, the estimates are wrong. Do you have valid statistics?

Comment: @wildplasser last statistics reset was today morning, so yes?

Comment: What **is** "statistics reset" ? In any case, I would start with `VACUUM ANALYZE;`

Comment: Inside `pgAdmin` under `Statistics` is the entry `Last statistics reset`. Did run `VACUUM ANALYZE` this morning.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slow query processes way more data (100000 vs. 2500 rows from `"Timestamp"`), so it is not surprising that it is slower.

You can force PostgreSQL to use a nested loop join with the slow query as well:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL enable_hashjoin = off;
SET LOCAL enable_mergejoin = off;
SELECT ...;
COMMIT;
```

Try that and see if PostgreSQL was right and the hash join is really slower.

I suspect that PostgreSQL is doing the right thing here, and the best way for you to improve the performance would be to increase `work_mem`.

If you are willing to add another index and to `VACUUM` `"Changes"` often enough, you could get even better performance with an index-only scan:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "Changes" ("idTimestamp") INCLUDE ("idJob");
```

On old versions of PostgreSQL that would be

```
CREATE INDEX ON "Changes" ("idTimestamp", "idJob");
```

Then you best drop the now unnecessary index `"index_Changes_idTimestamp"`.

By the way, you are making your life unnecessarily hard by using camel case and quoted identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Forcing the server to use a nested loop lead the 'slow query' to finish in ~400ms. I will need a bit more testing to add this to the application.
Increasing `work_mem` to 100MB did slightly speed up the query to ~6 seconds using 3765KB.
Ran `VACUUM` yesterday (and entries from `Changes` are not deleted) so i would assume this will not increase the performance.

Comment: Perhaps your indexes are cached, and you should increase `effective_cache_size`. Or if you have SSD storage, reduce `random_page_cost`. Both promote the use of indexes.  `VACUUM` without creating the extra index won't help.

Comment: The index creation statement you provided is rejected by the server with a syntax error at 'INCLUDE'.

Comment: Oh, you have an old version of PostgreSQL (you didn't tell your version). See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, the version of the server is `9.2`. Updated the question.

Comment: Then you should be able to get index-only scans with my second index suggestion. By the way, don't use 9.2. It is old and buggy.

Comment: After extensive testing i will force the use of nested loop for this specific query. When reducing the `random_page_cost` it would stretch the time period that will use the index and at some point omit it and create a performance gap. Thanks for your excellent help.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: your query is equivalent to:

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT "idJob"
FROM "Changes" ch
WHERE EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * FROM "Timestamp"  ts
        WHERE ts.id = ch."idTimestamp" 
        AND ts."usSince1970" between 1584831600000000 and 1584745200000000 
        );
```